# Time complexity of finding the GCD of a set S as a function of sum(S)

Tags: computational-complexity, nt.number-theory

The algorithm to be used is:

- Sort the set into ascending order
- $x_1 = s_1$
- $x_i = gcd(x_{i-1},s_i)$
- $GCD = x_n$

What I'm looking for is expected run time as a function of $\sum_{i\in S}i$

As a starting point $|S| \leq \sum_{i\in S} i$ and gcd is $O(ln(n))$ so an upper bound should be $O(n\ln(n))$.

Comment: I don't understand your algorithm. Suppose the set S is 6, 10, 15. Then $x_1=6$, $x_2=2$, $x_3=1$. How exactly do you propose to combine these numbers to get the LCM, which is 30?

Comment: Oops. I should have re-read the Wikipedia article, step 4 only works for 2 inputs.

Comment: I guess the whole thing doesn't work. OTOH the part I'm curious about is step 1-3 so, I'l fix the question to just ask about that.

Comment: You can modify it like this: keep the set of numbers $S$ and then $n - 1$ times extract two minimal elements from the set, calculate their $lcm$ and then put it back into the set.

Comment: That would solve the original problem as it was stated. However it doesn't exhibit the behavior I'm now interested in.

Comment: Solving the timing equations for the obvious divide & conquer algorithm gives me time $Cnlog(sn)$ where $n = |S|$ and $s = \sum S$ (with some laziness imposed assumptions on the distribution of the elements of $S$). Surely this has been well investigated. Names that pop to mind are Paul Zimmerman, Richard Brent, Brigitte Vallée, and Dan Bernstein; I'd check Dan's page first - http://cr.yp.to/djb.html

Comment: (I took the liberty of fixing a few minor typos.)

Comment: While I am in favor of numbers giving their approval, I think you want them to be in *ascending* rather than *assenting* order.

Answer (score 1):

Finding greatest common divisor ($gcd$) of two numbers of length $k$ takes $O(k)$ time. Suppose that all the numbers have equal length $k$, then complexity will be $O(nk)$, which is $O(n \log(\frac{S}{n}))$. This is in fact the case of maximum complexity for a fixed $n$ and $S$. Because in general case the time complexity be something like $O(\sum_i \log x_i)$ and from convexity of the $\log$ function it follows that maximum is achieved when all $\log x_i$ are equal.

Comment: Oops, that `$ln(n)^2$` should have been  `$ln(n)$`

Comment: I don't think that last bit holds. finding gdc takes `$O(min(k_1,k_2))$` and and for the special case where the next value is a multiple of the `gcd` so far it take `$O(1)$` so all the values being equal is a fast case. As for all the values being nearly equal, the `$x_i$` value will very quickly become small and again result in a fast case. OTOH what I'm interested in is the worst case and the average case.

Comment: Well, the big-O notation gives us an upper bound on the complexity, so the bounds I gave hold, but probably can be further improved.

Comment: It might be desirable to edit the claim on gcd complexity to either soft-oh notation, or to add the actual logarithmic factors that make the claim true. Except that, the answer is complete, probably can't do better than $nk$.

Comment: A correct upper bound on the complexity of computing the gcd of two integers of length k is $O(k log^2 k log log k)$, or more generally, $O(M(k) log k)$, where $M(k)$ is the cost of multiplication.  This bound is achieved by the algorithm of Knuth and Schonhage, and also by the algorithm of Stehle and Zimmermann, see http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.stehle/downloads/recbinary.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting a set of $n$ elements into ascending order takes $O(n\log n)$. You ask for a bound in terms of the sum, call it $T$, of the elements, rather than their number. I suspect that if the elements are all ones and twos and they are sufficiently jumbled up then there is no way to significantly improve on the time required to order them, and of course $T$ is within a constant multiple of $n$, so you still get $O(T\log T)$.

**Edit**: Exercise 36 in 4.5.3 of Knuth, Seminumerical Algorithms, may be relevant. The question asks, what is the smallest value of $u_n$ such that the calculation of $\gcd(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ [by the method of this question] requires $N$ divisions? The answer given is $u_n=F_{N-n+3}$, where $F_m$ is (I'm pretty sure) the $m$-th Fibonacci number. There's a reference to a paper of G H Bradley, CACM 13 (1970) 433-436, 447-448.

Comment: Assuming that I'm only using unique positive integers (as far as I know GDC is only defined for them and non unique value can be ignored) then you can approximate it as `$2n < \sqrt(T)$` so the sort is cheep (`$O(\sqrt(n)\ln(n))$`) and, I think, uninteresting to the big-o of finding `$GCD(S)$`.

Comment: The example of ones and twos is a bit off since ordering them takes $O(n)$ and not $O(n\log n)$ (bucket sort). Also, why is $T$ within a constant multiple of $n$?

Comment: "...if the elements are all ones and twos...$T$ is within a constant multiple of $n$". 

I hope BCS has a look at the Bradley paper, I think it has everything BCS needs. 

Comment: will someone please add a link to the article cited in this answer? http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/1970/7/12352-algorithm-and-bound-for-the-greatest-common-divisor-of-n-integers/abstract 

Comment: @Gerry: is the quote from a previous version of the question? I guess I got here after an edit. But still, sorting ones and twos is linear.

Comment: I think Gerry's right that Bradley's paper can show an upper bound of `$O(\ln(T/n) + n\ln(n))$` but I rather suspect that the upper bound is in fact much lower. (BTW, I love this line from page 435: "The assumption that nature is non-malicious leads one to expect fewer iterations than the bound would suggest."

Comment: @Dror, the quote is from the answer to which these comments are attached. $T$ is the sum of the elements. If there are $n$ elements, and they're all ones and twos, their sum is within a constant multiple of $n$. Indeed, it's between $n$ and $2n$. 

Comment: @BCS, how much better can the upper bound be? Suppose the numbers are $F_{k-1},F_k,1+F_k,\dots,n-2+F_k$. Then the sum, $T$, is roughly $nF_k$, and the gcd of $F_{k-1}$ and $F_k$ takes $O(\log F_k)$, which is $O\log(T/n)$. And putting the numbers in order in the first place is $O(n\log n)$. So it would seem that this case achieves the upper bound, no?