# complexity of greatest common divisor (gcd)

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider the following counting problem (or the associated decision problem): Given two positive integers encoded in binary, compute their greatest common divisor (gcd). What is the smallest complexity class this problem is contained in? Can you provide a reference?

In this question I am not primarily interested in asymptotic bounds on the running time, but rather in complexity classes. Is the problem in $AC$? In $AC^1$? Can it be proven not to lie in $AC^0$? What are other complexity classes inside $P$ that are of relevance here?

Comment: I don't know about the complexity classes, but I think this is the state of the art for gcd computation: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2008-77-261/S0025-5718-07-02017-0/home.html.

Comment: (a) There is a related MO post (which does not answer your question): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25055/time-complexity-of-finding-the-gcd-of-a-set-s-as-a-function-of-sums ; (b) This question would be seen by more complexity experts at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cross-posted this question on [stackexchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/complexity-of-greatest-common-divisor-gcd%20%22here%22) and John Watrous posted an answer. The gist was that it is not known whether gcd is in NC or P-complete. See, e.g., "J. Sorenson. Two fast GCD algorithms. Journal of Algorithms, 1994."

Comment: @ged: Do you know why, informally, should one conjecture that gcd is specifically in NC?

Comment: @Lukasz: I guess the main reason is that NC is one of the most well-known subsets of P. Another reason may be the ongoing quest for parallel gcd algorithms. However, if you know a different subset of P that you think is a more likely candidate, please let me know!